# Calling functions from an external C file that has its own main()

Tags: c

I have two C files, `program.c` and `tests.c`, that each contain a `main` function.

`program.c` is a standalone program, that compiles and run normally on its own. But I would like to also be able to use some of its functions in `tests.c` (without using a common header file). Is there a way of doing this?

If I insert the prototype of the function I want from `program.c` into `tests.c` and compile with:

```
gcc -o program.o -c program.c
gcc -o tests.o -c tests.c
gcc -o tests tests.o program.o
```

I obtain an error `duplicate symbol _main`, which I understand since there are indeed two `main' functions.

I basically would like to be able to treat `program.c` both as a standalone program and as a library, similarly to what could be done in Python with `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Comment: A simple technique is to rename `main` in `tests.c` and write `tests2.c` that contains `main` that just calls the renamed function in tests.c.  Then `program.c` can link with `tests.o` with no name clash.  This approach has problems, but is extremely easy to implement.

Comment: maybe, just brainstorming, `gcc tests.c -Dmain=mainp program.c` or vice versa

Comment: I think the closest equivalent to Python would be to guard `main` in `tests.c` with some preprocessor define that you set up in your build.

Comment: Your `gcc` command line option usage looks a bit weird.

Comment: One technique is to use a single program that can do both things, and have the program check its name in argv[0] to decide what to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have two separate distinct executables for which some of the functionality between them is similar you can share the common functionality by placing relevant functions into a third file, and compiling as a *portable executable*, [DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019) in Windows.  (or [shared library](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/linux-shared-libraries/) in Linux.)  Each of these file types contain sharable, executable code, ithout the `main()` function, designed to be linked during compile time, and dynamically loaded into your executable at runtime.

Here is a step by step set of instructions for [shared library using GCC and Linux](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html).
Here is a step by step example for creating [DLL using GCC in windows](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion... But here I would like to keep these functions in `program.c`. Otherwise I would just put the common function in a header.

Comment: @Ant A header should only declare functions (and a common header file is the safest way to do that), not define them (with some exceptions, such as `static inline` functions), and has nothing to do with linking.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to achieve what I wanted thanks to the comment from @pmg:

I compile program.c into a standalone binary (`gcc -o program program.c`), but I also compile it into an object file *with "main" renamed* (`gcc -c -Dmain=mainp -o program.o program.c`).

I can then use this object file (that does not contain a "main" symbol anymore) to compile tests.c: `gcc -o tests tests.c program.o`.

Thanks @pmg, I did not know this use of the -D option.